# Can i debug openACC with cuda-gdb? Or other debugging tools?

Tags: debugging, cuda-gdb, openacc

I'm using *CAPS OpenACC* on *CUDA*. I'm trying debugging with *cuda-gdb*. And i can debug normally c/c++ code with *cuda-gdb*. In other words i couldn't debug codelet code. Is there a anybody who debugged *openACC on cuda*? or i couldn't put breakpoint in the *codelet*. What should i do to debug?

I addition to i compiled with that 
`hmpp -d2 -kk -g gcc -g vecadd.c -o vecadd.x`

And my openACC code is very simple :

```
#pragma acc kernels copyin(a[0:n],b[0:n]), copyout(c[0:n])
for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](http://kb.caps-entreprise.com/how-to-debug-the-code-generated-by-caps-compilers/) you need to pass `-G` options to `capsmc` so that the CUDA code is compiled with debug symbols.

Since CAPS Compilers generates just plain CUDA code, you should be able to use `cuda-gdb` just fine then.